# Custom parent container for Angular material overlay container?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular material creates overlay containers for various components such as their menu, snackbar and dialog components.

How can I, in an easy way, decide which element a cdk-overlay-container should be appended to?

Currently, it's appended to the body element. So if I trigger full screen mode for any other element than the body element, it won't be seen. Which of course is not what I want.

Comment: This is the solution I've been using: https://blog.bbogdanov.net/post/angular-material-overlay-hack-overlay-container/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically create a class that extends `OverlayContainer`. Override the `getContainerElement` method where you return your HTML element which should be appended with the overlay. If needed, You can also override `_createContainer` method, where you do your own logic to create the element.

Finally provide your `CustomOverlayContainer` class as Token for `OverlayContainer` like this:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [{provide: OverlayContainer, 
                 useClass: CustomOverlayContainer}],
    // ...
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Just have a look at the origin file. It's quite easy: [OverlayContainer](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/overlay-container.ts)

Comment: I'm looking for this but with a difference, I want one dialog to open in a custom overlay container but all others to open at the default position. Do you have any advice for me? I've tried this solution but it overrides all dialog positions.

Comment: Hey @RuiAraújo ,you can do the exact same thing on component level instead of Module level. Have a look here https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the styling of mat-dialogue-container adding a panel class and giving style is enough, but in case if you want to change the styling of cdk-overlay-container then adding a backdropClass will help

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopupComponent, {
  backdropClass: 'popupBackdropClass',
  panelClass: 'custom-dialog-container',
  data: { data: data }
});
```

in component css add

```
.popupBackdropClass {
  background-color:yellow
}
```