# Angular Material Select - Customize Template

Tags: angular, angular-material

We are currently using NG Bootstrap and need to replace it for a variety of reasons.  I am advocating using Angular Material in its place.  However, for the multi-select dropdown we need the output of mat-select to look more like this:

[image: ng-dropdown example]

rather than this:

[image: mat-select example]

The thing to note is that each item is a separate widget, with a close link (the x) attached to it.  The link can be clicked, and clicking it removes the item.

Inspecting the output of the ng-select gives you this output:

```html
<div class="ng-value-container"><div class="ng-placeholder">Select States...</div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]",
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><div _ngcontent-c61="" class="ng-value"><span _ngcontent-c61="" class="ng-value-label"><i _ngcontent-c61="" class="icon-earth"></i> Alabama (AL)</span><span _ngcontent-c61="" aria-hidden="true" class="ng-value-icon right">×</span></div><div _ngcontent-c61="" class="ng-value"><span _ngcontent-c61="" class="ng-value-label"><i _ngcontent-c61="" class="icon-earth"></i> Arizona (AZ)</span><span _ngcontent-c61="" aria-hidden="true" class="ng-value-icon right">×</span></div><div _ngcontent-c61="" class="ng-value"><span _ngcontent-c61="" class="ng-value-label"><i _ngcontent-c61="" class="icon-earth"></i> California (CA)</span><span _ngcontent-c61="" aria-hidden="true" class="ng-value-icon right">×</span></div><!----><!----><div class="ng-input"><input role="combobox" type="text" autocomplete="a409ea53b6de" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="a409ea53b6de" aria-activedescendant="aa8ba66e7ecc"></div></div>
```

And inspecting the output of the mat-select gives you this output:

```html
<span class="ng-tns-c5-5 ng-star-inserted">Alabama (AL), Arizona (AZ), California (CA)</span>
```

As you can see, the latter just outputs a single blob of text, separated by commas.

Looking through the API documentation (https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) and examples (https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples) I don't see a way to do this.  Most of the searches I've done on google have produced results pertaining to styling and theming.  I did find this link ([Custom parent container for Angular material overlay container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871857/custom-parent-container-for-angular-material-overlay-container)) but it doesn't go into a lot of detail and I'm not even sure if that's what I'm trying to do.

Has anyone done this?  In ng-bootstrap it's very easy.  Just provide an ng-template with the correct directive, and it will override the default template.

Thank you.

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular material chips autocomplete component to achieve your desired output

https://stackblitz.com/angular/olggjybxblp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts

You can apply your css to look like your design

Comment: Wow.  Two great answers in under an hour.  Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the docs, you can specify a custom template for your selection. https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#customizing-the-trigger-label.

The `mat-select-trigger` is your custom template

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-select-trigger>
     <span class="custom" *ngFor="let top of toppings.value">
       {{top}}
     </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: The link demo has nothing to do with mat-select-trigger.

Comment: Thanks removed, I think it did at the time of writing, but i must have used that stackblitz for something else :(